# PDF of a uniform RV with a RV upper bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the PDF of a uniform RV that has a uniform RV upper bound -- in particular, the variable is uniformly distributed between 0 and Q, where Q is a random variable. The RV Q has PDF (1/ln 4) / q, with support between 0.25 and 1. I know that conditioned on Q taking the value q, the uniform RV has PDF 1/q, with support between 0 and q, but I'm not sure how to construct an explicit PDF for the uniform RV.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint PDF of your random variable $X$ and $Q$ is
$$ f_{X,Q}(x,q) = \cases{ \dfrac{1}{q^2 \ln 4} & if $0 \le x \le q$ and $1/4 \le q \le 1$\cr
0 & otherwise\cr}$$
To get the PDF for $X$, integrate with respect to $q$.  Be careful of the bounds: drawing a picture of the region in the $xq$ plane may help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Am I correct in understanding that after integrating over the appropriate cross-sections of the trapezoidal region in the xq-plane, we find that $f_X(x)=3\ln 4$ for $0\leq x \leq 0.25$ and $f_X(x)=(1/x-1)\ln 4$ for $0.25 \leq x \leq 1$?